# Start Activity with Button Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Ive got a problem. I want to open an Activity with a Button but it crashes all the time. 
So I created 2 Classes and A Button. But it keeps crashing.

1. Class is activity_home class() and second is   schedule_act() class.

**activity_home class:**

```
    package my.action.bat;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class activity_home extends Activity {

        private Button ScheduleBtn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

             ScheduleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_btn_schedule);

            ScheduleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent myIntent = new Intent("my.action.bat.schedule_act");
                    startActivity(myIntent);


                }
            });
        }





    }
```

**schedule_act class:**

```
package my.action.bat;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class schedule_act extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.schedule_layout);
        }



    }
```

**Android Manifest:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="my.action.bat"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".activity_home" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".schedule_act" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="my.action.bat.SCHEDULE_ACT" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Whats the exception being thrown??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Intents are case sensitive.  Change

```
"my.action.bat.schedule_act"
```

To

```
"my.action.bat.SCHEDULE_ACT"
```

Also, unless you really need to use an intent, I would start your activity like so

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, schedule_act.class));
```

Where `this` is a `Context` subclass

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
localIntent = new Intent(activity_home.this, schedule_act.class);
    activity_home.this.startActivity(localIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the line

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent("my.action.bat.schedule_act");
```

To

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), schedule_act.class);
```

And see if that helps.

See [here](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can change this line

`Intent myIntent = new Intent("my.action.bat.schedule_act");`
`startActivity(myIntent);`

To something like this

`Intent intent = new Intent ("Your context", "Your activity to launch");`
`startActivity(intent);`

Remember always especify a context and a activity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add all the activity classes to the manifest file!!